Kitchen sink water not draining though there is no clogging
I'm reaching out to you all in a bit of a panic as I'm facing a perplexing issue with my kitchen sink and dishwasher. Recently, I noticed that the water in my kitchen sink was not draining properly. Thinking it might be a simple clog, I checked the pipes and removed any obstructions. However, even after thorough cleaning and reassembly, the water still refuses to drain.

To further complicate matters, when I attempted to run my dishwasher to test the drainage, I was shocked to find that all the wastewater from the dishwasher began overflowing into the kitchen sink. This unexpected turn of events has left me baffled and in urgent need of assistance.
I've tried various troubleshooting steps, including checking for clogs, cleaning the pipes, and restarting both the sink and dishwasher multiple times, but nothing seems to be working. I'm at a loss as to what could be causing this issue and how to resolve it.
If anyone has encountered a similar problem or has any expertise in plumbing or appliance repair, I would greatly appreciate your advice and guidance. Please share any insights, tips, or suggestions you may have for diagnosing and fixing this issue.

Your general location will help, since that is an unusual drain setup for NA.  Poor draining is usually caused by a clog or blocked vent.  A clog can be quite far down the drain pipe, requiring snakes/wires to go down and reach.

hello @crip659, thanks for your reply. This setup is been 2 years, never had this problem since today. I checked all the pipes far down, even I put water from bottles to check and there were no clogging through far pipes.

It does not look like the best design for smooth water flow.  Is it just this sink that is having problems, all others draining fast?  House drains have two parts that work together, the drains and the vent/s(to let air in).  If the drain/s are clogged free then I would check for a blocked vent.

I am not a plumber, but that looks like more of a S-trap than the allowed P-trap, which might be part of the problem.  A plumbing system(even if wrong) might work for years, before something goes wrong.  If no other drains(sinks/toilets) are having problems, then replacing that drain under the sink might work.  It should be DIY for low price.  Google P-traps for how it should look.

Please take the [tour]. You'll notice that no other questions here have "fixed" in their titles.

@crip659 S-traps aren't allowed anymore because they are prone to siphoning, similar to a P-trap that has no vent. Siphoning occurs when water goes through an S-trap or unvented P-trap too fast, not too slow. It's a common misconception that a blocked vent will cause a slow drain, but it will actually cause the water to get "pulled" down the drain faster than it would otherwise, rather than some water being left in the trap as it should.

Since your dishwasher empties directly into the vertical drain the sink drain would act as a vent.  Yet you say it backs up into the sink!
You have a clog
You may not have found it with your limited examination...but it's there. (That sharp elbow would be my first suspect.)
Be absolutely sure all the pipes are clear. If so,disconnect the drain pipes as close to the wall or floor as you can (cannot see from the pic where the termination is). Try to snake the drain line from there.  You have a clog somewhere.

One thing that can help estimate how far away the clog is would be to fill the sink with water, then open the drain to send a large amount of water down all at once.  Depending on how long it takes for the water to stop flowing quickly, that can help tell if the clog is nearby or far away from the sink itself.  It's not perfect, but if it stops running very quickly, then the clog is likely near the sink.  If it runs for several seconds or more before slowing down, that likely indicates a clog farther along in the drain pipes.

I removed one by one few of the pipes from top and threw enough water into the below open pipe to see if it was still clogging and yes it was clogging deep down to the pipes. I threw enough hot water again to the pipe and give a air blow from my mouth to in the pipe (this is a change moment). I initially felt hard to blow air, I threw water again and gave air blow again and 2nd time, I felt air blow is not that hard than the previous time. I connected all the pipes again, I let water flow from my tap on full speed and there was no water clogging anymore.

I'm glad you figured it out, but you've essentially done what RMDman suggested in his answer. You should've upvoted and accepted that answer instead of posting your own very similar answer. Take the [tour].

Instead of disassembling the pipes and putting your mouth on clogged plumbing, use a plunger.
